# How to add reward point to all products at once in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

How to add reward point to all products at once instead of adding manually to each product? This is time consuming to add point to each product manually instead I want to add 2% of product price to reward point.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily perform sql querys in phpmyadmin to update points.

Assuming your table name **oc_product** and point column name **points**

```
UPDATE oc_product SET points = price * 0.02 WHERE price > 0
```

**take backup of your OC database before performing queries**

Comment: Yes i know that. I need that single query to append all data automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much it's sorted my problem.

Comment: How can we write same query for oc_product_reward table their is also point for specific product? because price field is in product table not in this table. Can you help me in this?

Comment: To achieve that you have use JOIN & SUB QUERIES